# socketio can't create room

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to dynamically create a room. I get an id which will be the name of the room. In the callback I see list of rooms using `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` and  I don't see the room I joined.

```
io.of('/chat').on('connection', (socket) => {
 const socketQuery = socket.handshake.query;
 if(socketQuery.action === 'createRoom' && socketQuery.doctorUserId){

   console.log("Creating room", socketQuery.doctorUserId);
   socket.join("A ROOM", () => console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms)); //I want the id here to be the name of the room
}
```

I tried to just give some text(A ROOM) and still don't see the room name in the callback.

I see this in the console.log:

`Creating room 5e972498125a3d1488d0985f
{ 'tHlX-TYkQeVlxEB9AAAA': Room { sockets: { 'tHlX-TYkQeVlxEB9AAAA': true }, length: 1 } }
Creating room 5e972498125a3d1488d0985f
{ pZe_38mllgVtSUfrAAAB: Room { sockets: { pZe_38mllgVtSUfrAAAB: true }, length: 1 },
  '7oZdWV9mwvuhnvQTAAAC': Room { sockets: { '7oZdWV9mwvuhnvQTAAAC': true }, length: 1 } }`

*Edit* It works if I don't use namespace and just do join. What am I doing wrong

Comment: May I suggest you check https://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets to see if your browser supports websockets?

Comment: Socket.io checks if a browser uses WebSockets if it does than socket.io uses WebSockets as well if it doesn't it uses a "WebSocket hack" (i.e. polling) to send and receive messages